# Accessing MySQL GCP from circle ci to automate database migration?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, flyway, circleci

I am trying to run database migration on Cloud MySQL GCP from circle ci, the problem is that Cloud MySQL GCP allows access for a specified IP addresses as described in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/authorize-networks)
However, circle ci jobs have dynamic ip addresses each time a new job get started so we can't anticipate the ip address ahead, and I don't want to enable all IP ranges (0.0.0.0/0) for security reasons.
is there a way to connect to Cloud MySQL other than specifying the IP address in the authorized network?
Or is there a way to configure authorized networks on Cloud sql with circle ci job dynamic IP on the fly?

Comment: Does the Circle Ci process have the ability to run the job via ssh?  That way you can validate through PEM key pairs.   I would never open a database port public facing even if it's only looking for a specified IP -- Just asking for trouble .. I think CircleCi should be able to SSH into your container and issue the MySQL commands directly.(but don't hold me to that -- Otherwise I'd answer the post!)

Comment: @Zak Thanks for your comment, but I don't get what you mean by this statement "(but don't hold me to that -- Otherwise I'd answer the post!) "

Comment: He means he's not completely sure it is possible to do

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Cloud SQL Auth proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy). The Cloud SQL Auth proxy provides secure access to your instance using authentication, such as service accounts. You can try the [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/quickstart-proxy-test) and check if it fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

That Auth Proxy is not needed.

You could run your Circle jobs on a predefined set of IP ranges.

More info here: https://circleci.com/docs/ip-ranges/

Within cloud sql, you then grant access to the IP ranges indicated by CircleCI.